# Why MySQL full outer join returns nulls?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Why MySQL full outer join returns nulls?

Hi

I have the following data:

```
s_id,date,p_id,amount_sold
1, '2015-10-01', 1, 10
2, '2015-10-01', 2, 12
7, '2015-10-01', 1, 11
3, '2015-10-02', 1, 11
4, '2015-10-02', 2, 10
5, '2015-10-15', 1, 22
6, '2015-10-16', 2, 20
8, '2015-10-22', 3, 444
```

and i want my query to output something like this: (A = sum of amount_sold for p_id=1 for that date,B = sum of amount_sold for p_id=2 for that date)

```
date,A,B,Difference
'2015-10-01',21,12,9
'2015-10-02',11,10,1
'2015-10-15',22,0,22
'2015-10-01',0,20,-20
```

I tried with this query, but the order its returning is having NULLS and the output is wrong:

```
SELECT A.p_id,A.date,sum(A.amount_sold) A,B.Bs, (sum(A.amount_sold) - B.Bs) as difference FROM sales as A
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT SUM( amount_sold ) Bs,p_id,s_id, DATE
FROM sales
WHERE p_id =2
group by date

) as B ON A.s_id = B.s_id
where A.p_id=1 or B.p_id=2 
group by A.date, A.p_id

UNION

SELECT A.p_id,A.date,sum(A.amount_sold) A,B.Bs, (sum(A.amount_sold) - B.Bs) as difference FROM sales as A
RIGHT JOIN (

SELECT SUM( amount_sold ) Bs,p_id,s_id, DATE
FROM sales
WHERE p_id =2
group by date

) as B ON A.s_id = B.s_id
where B.p_id=2 
group by A.date, A.p_id
```

It returned:

```
p_id    date        A   Bs  difference  
1   2015-10-01  21  NULL    NULL
2   2015-10-01  12  12  0
1   2015-10-02  11  NULL    NULL
2   2015-10-02  10  10  0
1   2015-10-15  22  NULL    NULL
2   2015-10-16  20  20  0
```

What am i doing wrong here? and what is the correct way of doing it? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A full join isn't needed. You can use conditional aggregation instead:

```
select 
    date,
    sum(case when p_id = 1 then amount_sold else 0 end) a,
    sum(case when p_id = 2 then amount_sold else 0 end) b,
    sum(case when p_id = 1 then amount_sold else 0 end) 
     - sum(case when p_id = 2 then amount_sold else 0 end) difference
from sales
where p_id in (1,2)
group by date
```